# Determinant of sparse Hilbert matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, symmetric-matrices, hilbert-matrices, cauchy-matrices

[It is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix) that the determinant of the Hilbert matrix of dimension $N$ with elements
$$
H^N_{tr}=\frac{1}{t+r-1}, \quad t,r=1,\dots,N
$$
namely of the form
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \dots \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5} & \dots \\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{6} & \dots \\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{7} & \dots \\
\frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{8} & \dots \\
\vdots      & \vdots      & \vdots      & \vdots      & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}
decreases exponentially to zero as
$$
\det H^N \approx a_N N^{-1/4} (2\pi)^N 4^{-N^2} .
$$
I was wondering how the scaling of this matrix would change if we considered instead its elements being of the form
$$
H^{N,S}_{tr}=\frac{1}{t+r-1}, \quad t,r \in \{ 1, S+1, 2S+1, \dots, NS+1 \}
$$
namely ``skipping'' some values, obtaining for instance, by taking $S=3$, a matrix of the form
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{10} & \dots \\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{13} & \dots \\
\frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{13} & \frac{1}{16} & \dots \\
\frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{13} & \frac{1}{16} & \frac{1}{19} & \dots \\
\frac{1}{13} & \frac{1}{16} & \frac{1}{19} & \frac{1}{22} & \dots \\
\vdots      & \vdots      & \vdots      & \vdots      & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}